# What happened with formatter %r and \n in Python?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm learning Learn Python the Hard Way. Here is the content in exercise9’s Common Student Questions

**Why do the \n newlines not work when I use %r?**

**That's how %r formatting works, it prints it the way you wrote it (or close to it). It's the "raw" format for debugging**

Then I tried it, but it works on me!

My code：

```
# test %r with \n
print "test\n%r\n%r" % ("with", "works?")

# change a way to test it
print "%r\n%r" % ("with", "works?")
```

Output：

```
test
'with'
'works?'
'with'
'works?'
```

It confuses me, is there something wrong with my test or the book?
Can you show me some examples? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you expect the `\n` to not be interpreted as newlines? You are confusing the value being interpolated with the string syntax itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not where you'll see the effects of `%r`. Put escaped characters like a linefeed (`'\n'`) into the strings that will replace `%r`:

```
>>> print "%r\n%r" % ("with\n", "works?")
'with\n'
'works?'
```

Now use `%s`, which replaces with the `str()` representation instead of the `repr()` representation, to see the difference:

```
>>> print "%s\n%s" % ("with\n", "works?")
with

works?
```

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing *raw string literals* with the `%r` (`repr()`) string formatter. They are not the same thing.

You defined a string literal:

```
'This is a string with a newline\n'
```

This produces a string object. You then used that string object with the `%` operator, which let you replace any `%`-marked placeholders with values based on whatever you put on the right-hand side of the `%` operator. The `%r` placeholder uses `repr()` to produce a string for a given object and inserts that string into the slot.

If you expected `\n` to be interpreted as a literal backslash and separate `n` character, use a *raw string literal*, prefixed by `r`:

```
r'This is a string with a literal backslash and letter n: \n'
```

If you expected `%r` to produce the escaped (Python) syntax, put the newline into the value on the right; `repr()` string produces string literal syntax:

```
'This will show the string in Python notation: %r' % ('String with \n newline',)
```

This takes the output of `repr('String with \n newline')` and inserts it into the string:

```
>>> 'String with \n newline'
'String with \n newline'
>>> repr('String with \n newline')
"'String with \\n newline'"
>>> print repr('String with \n newline')
'String with \n newline'
>>> 'This will show the string in Python notation: %r' % ('String with \n newline',)
"This will show the string in Python notation: 'String with \\n newline'"
>>> print 'This will show the string in Python notation: %r' % ('String with \n newline',)
This will show the string in Python notation: 'String with \n newline'
```